# How to remove a symbol along with the newline in Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I have a String like below

```
  <P><STRONG>Hi Bold</STRONG></P>
  <P><U>Hi Underline</U></P>
  <P><STRONG><EM>Hi Bold Italic</EM></STRONG></P>
  <P><STRONG><FONT color=3D#8080ff>Hi Bold Purple</FONT></STRONG></P>
  <P><IMG style=3D"HEIGHT: 152px; WIDTH: 203px" border=3D0 hspace=3D0 al=
  t=3D"Inline Image with alt" src=3D"cid:/Downloads/axie_generated(1).pn=
  g" width=3D1198 align=3Dbaseline height=3D900></P>
  <P><IMG style=3D"HEIGHT: 183px; WIDTH: 188px" border=3D0 hspace=3D0 al=
  t=3D"" src=3D"cid:/Desktop/potato.gif" width=3D495 align=3Dbaseline he=
  ight=3D497></P>
  <UL>
  <LI>List Item</LI>
  <LI><FONT color=3D#8080ff>List Item Purple</FONT></LI></UL>
  <P><FONT color=3D#000000>Stream <A href=3D"https://open.spotify.com/tr=
  ack/42DD4cLqkprJPih3YxXkAO?si=3Dc68ba6d1617d488d">Forever Rain</A></FO=
  NT></P>
```

If the line is too long it will break into a new line with `=\n`. How can I remove and join the string back into one line without removing the other wanted `=` in the String?

I have tried `replaceAll('=\n', '')` which does nothing and I have also tried `replaceAll('\n', '')` which successfully remove the newline but the `=` is still there. If  I proceed with `replaceAll('=', '')` then it will remove all the `=` including the ones that I want to keep

This is the output after using `replaceAll('=\n', '')`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. It was because `\r` is also present in the String. Therefore, using `replaceAll('=\r\n', '')` helps me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

That's strange: I just ran this in a DartPad

```
const string =
  '<P><STRONG>Hi Bold</STRONG></P>'
  '<P><U>Hi Underline</U></P>'
  '<P><STRONG><EM>Hi Bold Italic</EM></STRONG></P>'
  '<P><STRONG><FONT color=3D#8080ff>Hi Bold Purple</FONT></STRONG></P>'
  '<P><IMG style=3D"HEIGHT: 152px; WIDTH: 203px" border=3D0 hspace=3D0 al=\n'
  't=3D"Inline Image with alt" src=3D"cid:/Downloads/axie_generated(1).pn=\n'
  'g" width=3D1198 align=3Dbaseline height=3D900></P>'
  '<P><IMG style=3D"HEIGHT: 183px; WIDTH: 188px" border=3D0 hspace=3D0 al=\n'
  't=3D"" src=3D"cid:/Desktop/potato.gif" width=3D495 align=3Dbaseline he=\n'
  'ight=3D497></P>'
  '<UL>'
  '<LI>List Item</LI>'
  '<LI><FONT color=3D#8080ff>List Item Purple</FONT></LI></UL>'
  '<P><FONT color=3D#000000>Stream <A href=3D"https://open.spotify.com/tr=\n'
  'ack/42DD4cLqkprJPih3YxXkAO?si=3Dc68ba6d1617d488d">Forever Rain</A></FO=\n'
  'NT></P>';

void main() {
  print(string.replaceAll('=\n', ""));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and the output looks just as imagined, with no '=' or '\n'[image]

Comment: I tried it on DartPad and it works too but when I code it in Flutter, the `=\n` is still there. You can check out the screenshot in my post that I just updated